# Create multiple arrays from a given string array

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I have an array of unique strings from which i need to create all possible arrays with the same length.

```
String[] str = {"Belgium", "France", "Germany"};
```

The goal is to create a list of arrays which have every possible value from above array at each index,

```
[Belgium, Belgium, Belgium]
[Belgium, Belgium, France]
[Belgium, Belgium, Germany]
[Belgium, France, Belgium]
[Belgium, France, France]
[Belgium, France, Germany]
[Belgium, Germany, Belgium]
[Belgium, Germany, France]
[Belgium, Germany, Germany]
[France, Belgium, Belgium]

....

[Germany, Germany, France]
[Germany, Germany, Germany]
```

My code to create this looks like

```
static List<String[]> getAllAllocations(String[] input){
    List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
    if(input.length == 2){
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
                result.add(new String[]{input[i], input[j]});
            } 
        }
    }
    else if(input.length == 3){
        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++){
                    result.add(new String[]{input[i], input[j], input[k]});
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    else if(input.length == 4){
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k < 4; k++){
                    for(int m = 0; m < 4; m++){
                        result.add(new String[]{input[i], input[j], input[k], input[m]});
                    }
                }
            } 
        }
    }
    //else if(input.length == 5) similar code with 5 for loops
    //else if(input.length == 6) similar code with 6 for loops
    //else if(input.length == 7) similar code with 7 for loops
    //else if(input.length == 8) similar code with 8 for loops
    return result;
}
```

The array will have a variable length between 2 and 8. How can I dynamicaly create the for loops instead of chaining the if-else checks or any other way to do this in an elganter way than I did above?

Comment: The magic word here is recursion!

Comment: @Rocco I have tried recursion, but it was difficult and I had problems to add a string to an existing array. I would appreciate a little more input how to solve this using recursion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recursive solution

```
public static List<String[]> getAllAllocations(String[] input) {
    List<String[]> result=new ArrayList<String[]>();
    getAllAllocations(result, input, new String[input.length], 0);
    return result;
}

public static void getAllAllocations(List<String[]> result, String[] input, String[] current, int depth) {
    if (depth>=input.length) {
        result.add(current.clone());
    } else {
        for (int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
            current[depth]=input[i];
            getAllAllocations(result, input, current, depth+1);
        }
    }
}
```

Iterative solution

```
public static List<String[]> getAllAllocations2(String[] input) {
    List<String[]> result=new ArrayList<String[]>();
    
    int[] counters=new int[input.length];
    
    boolean done=false;
    while (!done) {
        
        String[] comb=new String[input.length];
        for (int i=0;i<comb.length;i++) {
            comb[i]=input[counters[i]];
        }
        result.add(comb);

        done=true;
        for (int i=0;i<counters.length;i++) {
            counters[i]++;
            if (counters[i]>=input.length) {
                counters[i]=0;
            } else {
                done=false;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. i didn't fully understand what is going on, specially in the second method but tested it with different inputs and this works as desired. Thank you again.

Comment: @Biscuit the second method is recursively generating the combinations, by rotating the input elements in the current array. Each level of recursion is responsible of rotating the depth-th element of array, when the last level is reached the combination is complete and added to the result. Since the current array is mutable it must be cloned to avoid side effect on the result.

Comment: @Biscuit I also added an iterative solution, but in my opinion it's even more obscure of recursion in this case

Comment: The specific term for what Rocco is using in the recursive approach is called backtracking. It's an algorithm generally used for combination/permutation based problems. Check out this article -- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/backtracking-introduction/

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand how it works. Thanks again for the other approach Rocco and the link @Tim Tong

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` and `reduce` approach:

1. `map` - first prepare the lists of arrays `List<String[]>`. An array of three elements becomes three lists of singleton arrays:

   ```
   list1: [[Belgium], [France], [Germany]]
   list2: [[Belgium], [France], [Germany]]
   list3: [[Belgium], [France], [Germany]]
   ```
2. `reduce` - then multiply these lists sequentially one by one and get the *Cartesian product*. Two steps of reduction for three lists:

   ```
   list1: [[Belgium], [France], [Germany]]
   list2: [[Belgium], [France], [Germany]]
   ------
    sum1: [[Belgium, Belgium], [Belgium, France], ..., [Germany, Germany]]
   ```

   ```
    sum1: [[Belgium, Belgium], [Belgium, France], ..., [Germany, Germany]]
   list3: [[Belgium], [France], [Germany]]
   ------
   total: [[Belgium, Belgium, Belgium], [Belgium, Belgium, France], ...]
   ```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVTBTuMwEL33K0Y9OVIx0GNhKy0rdoUEAom9rTgMqRvcdezInoCqqt9exnGSLUoBLb4kmnlv5s0bJyt8xiNXKbta/N3tdFk5T7DioKxJG/nde1yHs9Eg8cMZo3LSzh7KXutAB8KBvMKy4zof3sdcWbpv3t6HdPlRVT8anUNuMAS4QW1hMwI@bTwQEj@enV5AyVnBRG2LPw@AvghZC46nT3AH@Aab8YUyha7L8QTGPz3aXMW3X8qXaNfj7VlPzNGTChrtnXeLOifBBTK5dP4S8yeB3sPRHO7XgVQpXU2y4j5krEj2SnKpc0RmWZbqbkfNo1UfHT3v9M2HDXvp2lY17Q/lFdXeQm@o5EEKJU4mCSqNsgU9ZT2@O8fHkAjnb3vPB0hZYvXb3T6uhI5ztkOlLYmkZ8DZ50a3ItGql34FG45tP6Dl6Q6Jf3eJXYxCBRt4aJYkB9wSDKMCkAOEwL2MaiLDqbxiZ5UQMXs6aUDTLOpsAt18H2hcGqQbHo@3etrxpp/z3ljD3GlzedLu3LKpNoEY/7zEQErazWyWRPxHAXINtb9nsxlv65DVX9yQ5G/FBCX2/itSlRWtW0b3TWx3u1c)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] str = {"Belgium", "France", "Germany"};
    cartesianProduct(str).forEach(arr->System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
}
```

```java
static List<String[]> cartesianProduct(String[] input) {
    return IntStream.range(0, input.length)
            // Stream<List<String[]>>
            .mapToObj(i -> Arrays.stream(input)
                    .map(str -> new String[]{str})
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            // stream of lists to a single list
            .reduce((list1, list2) -> list1.stream()
                    .flatMap(arr1 -> list2.stream()
                            .map(arr2 -> Stream.of(arr1, arr2)
                                    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                                    .toArray(String[]::new)))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()))
            .orElse(Collections.emptyList());
}
```